# Facebook IOS Sdk Invite friends to download App

Tags: ios

I have an invite feature to ask friends to download App.
These are my approach
1. The approach below required canvas page which i don't have.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                  message:@"MCommerce - World Class App"
                                                    title:nil
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                          NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                              // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                              NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                          } else {
                                                              NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                          }
                                                      }}];
```

1. Post to friends wall. I am using FeedDialog and posting to friend wall is disabled by Facebook.

Any alternate way of sending an invite to ask friend download the App?